# Open a random page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, hyperlink

I'm newbie, I'm trying to create a redirect.html page which will send a visitor to a random site as soon as he open the redirect page. Please help to edit the following code, I think the issue is in this line:

```
"echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;URL="openLink();">"
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Create an array of the links to choose from:
var links = new Array();
links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
links[1] = "http://www.bing.com/";
links[2] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
links[3] = "http://www.apple.com/";

function openLink() {
  // Chooses a random link:
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
  // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
  parent.location = links[i];
  return false;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;URL="openLink();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you do it with a server-side redirect? Are you aware of them?

Comment: Don't mix up back end and front end parts of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attach javascript functions to the meta tag. Put your `openLink()` call on the  tag, alternatively within the body of the page.

```
<body onload="openLink();">
```

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click check the answer that you believe answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the  section and not in the   (basically placed in a tag before any information is returned to the browser).

Secondarily, using the META tag isn't the best format to use these days but if you have to use it : you can use Javascript to build a META tag, using something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = new Array("http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com/");

function redirect()
{
    window.location = urls[Math.floor(urls.length*Math.random())];
}
var temp = setInterval("redirect()", 3000);
</script>
```

But, as per your code, remove the openLink() call from the META tag and place it on the onload:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Create an array of the links to choose from:
var links = new Array();
links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
links[1] = "http://www.bing.com/";
links[2] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
links[3] = "http://www.apple.com/";

function openLink() {
  // Chooses a random link:
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
  // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
  parent.location = links[i];
  return false;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="openLink();">
</body>
</html>
```